# Where do I post my project source code for review by other developers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I post source codes of a project of mine,  which I currently develop and which will be an OpenSource project?

Answer (score 4):

Such an extensive code review is out of scope for any Stack Exchange site.

For specific bits of code - whole classes, for example, you can use [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), though you should read their FAQ before posting.

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review.

Comment: no... whole project is in one file-only, and not larger than 200 lines!

Comment: @ZlatanO. - It really depends on the size. If you are talking about a single 200 line code file, that should be fine. If a project contains many source files, that's out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so on **[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)**. It's exactly why it's there.

Comment: For whole projects?

Comment: @Oded: No, I assumed "Codes of a project of mine" means he's planning to post parts of it.